# Merging one named branch into another (catching up), but keeping the two branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

We have two named branches in Mercurial:

- "default" - a "bugfixing" branch where we fix bugs
- "redesign" named branch where we do a whole new UI-design for the app

Now, I'd like to merge my "bugfixing" branch into the "redesign" branch. But keeping the "bugfixing" branch **untouched**.

In other words, I want to update my named branch from default, but without actually merging the branches. Can't figure a way to that...

Should I just do

```
hg merge default
```

while in my named branch? But will this keep the two branches?

PS. I'm quite new to hg, sorry if this is a stupid question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to update my named branch from default, but without actually merging the branches

I.e **you want** merge branches in terms of Mercurial - merge default to redesign. In Mercurial branch-merge does not mean "You can't use merged branch anymore" - you can, just update to branch head, edit and commit

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Mercurial branches, as we use Kiln "branch repositories" (basically clones of a repo stored on the server alongside the originals). When we merge changes ffrom one repo to another, it doesn't modify the original one, it's more of "copying changes from branch A into branch B" than merging. It's possible that Mercurial branches work exactly the same.

The easiest way to test it, is to clone the repo somewhere, and do the merges. As long as you don't push, p you can just throw away that clone when you're done testing. Merge the branches, see if they both remain (I suspect they will, unless you explicitly close one, though which branch you're on, and which you merge, will give opposite results!) with the changes you want. You can always use "hg rollback" to quickly revert the last operation and try different things.

Comment: Tnx for the clone tip Dan! "Just test it". So simple and obvious... Awesome. Why havent I though about this myself...

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial didnt deletes your branch after you merge Alex, it just get the files from the src (redesign) branch and merge it with the target(default) branch. Your team mate will keep working in the src branch after that and if you want pull the next versions again you just have to perform the merge again.

After that you can decide if you want to push the merged one that is your default now or if you will wait until the branch get's stable to do it.